# how to compile Marble (KDE) on macOS? No pre built package available

Tags: terminal, command-line, install, homebrew, open-source

Marble is an Open Source alternative to Apple Maps / Google Earth:

> Versatile, yet easy to use. Use Marble similar to a desktop globe; pan
>   around and measure distances. At closer scale it becomes a world
>   atlas, while OpenStreetMap takes you to street level. Search for
>   places of interest, view Wikipedia articles, create routes by drag and
>   drop and so much more.

From [marble.kde.org](https://marble.kde.org/install.php) deep link `http://files.kde.org/marble/downloads/MacOSX/Marble-1.5.0.dmg`

> Mac OS X Desktop
>
> The Mac OS X installer is outdated. We recommend compiling the latest
>   stable version yourself.

Homebrew

```
> brew cask search Marble
==> Exact Match
marble

> brew cask info marble
marble: 1.5.0
https://marble.kde.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/marble.rb
==> Name
Marble
==> Artifacts
Marble.app (app)
```

there is no guide how to compile on macOS from source.

Comment: Shouldn't "brew install marble" compile it properly?

Comment: Here is the compile instructions: https://github.com/KDE/marble/blob/master/install/INSTALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pre-built application for Marble. You can install it with :

```
brew cask install marble
```

It will install it as a standard application on :

```
/Applications/Marble.app
```

Comment: its old version